# webpackHtmlPlugin: control the order of injected files

Tags: webpack

I use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` for auto generate the `index.thml` with the output of webpack compile.

for performance reason I split my entries to *vendors* and *project*

like that:

```
...
entry:{
    vendors:'./vendors.js'
    ,TimerApp:'./src/index.js'

},
output:{
    path: path.join(__dirname,'build'),
    filename:'[name].js'
},
...
```

when I run the project by `webpack-dev-server`:

`set NODE_ENV=development && webpack-dev-server -d --hot --port 4040 --content-base src/"`

I get `index.html`

```
<head>
...
    <title>Timer Task</title>
    <link href="vendors.css"  rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="TimerApp.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body >
 ...
<script src="vendors.js"></script>
<script src="TimerApp.js"></script>
```

`verdor.js` first and `TimerApp.js` second. and that perfect.

but.. when I use webpack:

`webpack --colors --watch --optimize-dedupe`

the order is `TimerApp.js` first and `vendors.js` second 
and that make exception every time project compiled

very annoyed.

**so, what is the way to control the order of the output files ??**

reference: `webpack.js` file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var ngAnnotatePlugin = require('ng-annotate-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var exportRunTimeVariable = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   MODE: {
    production: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
   }
});

var extractSCSS =  new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css");

module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    devtool: 'source-map', /*devtool: 'inline-source-map'*/
    context: __dirname, /*for node key*/
    node:{
        __filename:true,
        __dirname:true
    },
    resolve: {
        root:[
            path.resolve('src')
            ,path.resolve('node_modules')
            ,path.resolve('bower_components')
        ]
        //root: __dirname + '/src'
    },
    entry:{
        vendors:'./vendors.js'
        ,TimerApp:'./src/index.js'

    },
    output:{
        path: path.join(__dirname,'build'),
        filename:'[name].js'
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            /*
            test: A condition that must be met
            exclude: A condition that must not be met
            include: A condition that must be met
            loader: A string of "!" separated loaders
            loaders: A array of loaders as string
            */
            {test:/\.css$/,
                loader:extractSCSS.extract('style-loader?sourceMap','css-               loader!sass-loader')},

        {test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: extractSCSS.extract('style-loader?sourceMap','css-loader!sass-loader')},

        {test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'ng-annotate',
            exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/},

        {test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)(\?]?.*)?$/,
            loader : 'file-loader?name=res/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        },
        //{test: /index\.html$/,
        //    loader : 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
        //},

        {test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'raw'
            ,exclude:[/index.html/]},

        {test: /\.json/,
            loader: 'json'}

    ]
},
plugins: [
    extractSCSS,
    exportRunTimeVariable,
    new ngAnnotatePlugin({
        add: true
            // other ng-annotate options here
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Timer Task'
            //,filename: ''
            ,template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to set chunksSortMode with a sort function.

> chunksSortMode: Allows to control how chunks should be sorted before they are included to the html. Allowed values: 'none' | 'auto' | 'dependency' | {function} - default: 'auto'

https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin

```
//...
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: 'Timer Task',
    template: 'src/index.html',
    chunksSortMode: function (a, b) {  //alphabetical order
      if (a.names[0] > b.names[0]) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.names[0] < b.names[0]) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
})
//...
```

Answer (score 6):

```
chunksSortMode: function (chunk1, chunk2) {
    var order = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
    var order1 = order.indexOf(chunk1.names[0]);
    var order2 = order.indexOf(chunk2.names[0]);
    return order1 - order2;  
}
```

Comment: You made my day! @Alan

Answer (score 1):

@panlilu 's answer is good, but could be simplified:

```
chunksSortMode: 'none'
```

Comment: where does this go?

Comment: @chovy this goes in your webpack config file. The OP has called theirs `webpack.js`