# How to use chunksSortMode in HtmlWebpackPlugin / webpack 2

Tags: webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

I have an issue with the order of my chunks inserted in index.html.

I'm using webpack2 and HtmlWebpackPlugin.

I think what is controlling the order of the chunk is the chunksSortMode option.

The [documentation](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) for HtmlWebpackPlugin is saying:

> chunksSortMode: Allows to control how chunks should be sorted before
> they are included to the html. Allowed values: 'none' | 'auto' |
> 'dependency' |'manual' | {function} - default: 'auto'

**What is the difference between:**

- **none**
- **auto**
- **dependency**
- **manual**

For the 'function' option, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725384/webpackhtmlplugin-control-the-order-of-injected-files) gave me insight

It's likely that I don't understand something basic as I would expect to find this info in the documentation from the start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this file may help you, it's well commented.
[chunksorter](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/lib/chunksorter.js)

#### short summary:

**none:** performs identity mapping (no-sort).

**auto:** sort by chunk Id

**dependency:** sorts dependencies between chunks by their "parents" attribute.

**manual:** sort manually by the chunks:

- @param  {Array} chunks the chunks to sort
- @return {Array} The sorted chunks

Comment: Thanks, at least it is something!

Comment: Although it's accepted answer, I still don't get anything from this answer at all. Yay, at least it's something.

Comment: Seems like from that chunksorter code that the auto and none are exactly the same...